# Multiple express's routers using the root path

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I run into a trouble using the express's router.

Here is a sample of code :

```
// file.js (1st to be imported)
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use('/', fileRouter);
};

fileRouter.get('/file', /* do stuff */ );

// user.js
module.exports = function (app) {
    app.use('/', userRouter);
};

userRouter.get('/user', /* do stuff */ );
userRouter.get('/userList', /* do stuff */ );
```

We cannot prefix our routers and we want not to change our path architecture.

It seems that the two regex routers are added but duplicated.

It might look like :

```
/
=> /file

/
=> /user
=> /userList
```

Instead of

```
/
=> /file
=> /user
=> /userList
```

So instead of looking for the two routers, it stops at the first one.

Do you know how we can address this problem ?

Comment: Express router are look like middle-ware, In express `app.use` is like declare/adding another middle-ware. So that may not be duplicate. But if you use `/:file` like that you have to do another way to handle.

Answer (score 0):

If a route matches and you still want the subsequent routes to run if they match, then use the third function parameter of the route's callback:

```
userRouter.get( '/', function( req, res, next ) {  
  /* Do something... */
  next();
});
```